# Serialize Java default classes?

Tags: java, serialization

I'm busy creating a modification/plugin to an existing application, my modification includes a Rhino JavaScript scripting engine, the only problem I have is that the ScriptEngine and ScriptEngineManager aren't serializable, this wouldn't be a problem if I could save all the data. How could I do this?

```
var vertices = RenderUtils.createSquareVertices(64);
var indices = RenderUtils.createSquareIndices();

var mesh = RenderUtils.newStaticMesh(vertices, indices, true);
var textureThingy = RenderUtils.newTexture("NULL.png", Sys.getAssetDir());
var materialThingy = RenderUtils.newMaterial(textureThingy, Math.newVector3f(1, 1, 1), 1, 1);
var renderMesh = RenderUtils.newMeshRenderer(mesh, materialThingy);
var rotationAngle = 0.0;

function update() {
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(0)) rotationAngle=rotationAngle + 1.0;
    if(Mouse.isButtonDown(1)) rotationAngle=rotationAngle - 1.0;
}

function render() {
    renderMesh.getTransform().getPos().setVector(Sys.getWidth()/2, Sys.getHeight()/2, 0);
    renderMesh.getTransform().setRotation(Math.newVector3f(0, 0, 1), rotationAngle);
    renderMesh.render();
}
```

The java side:

```
public void start() {
    try {
        this.Script.eval(this.ApplicationCode);
    } catch(ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void update() {
    if(this.hasUpdateFunc) {
        try {
            if(this.Script != null) ((Invocable)this.Script).invokeFunction("update");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void render() {
    if(this.hasRenderFunc) {
        try {
            if(this.Script != null) ((Invocable)this.Script).invokeFunction("render");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save all the data"? What data?

Comment: Mark those fields as `transient`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza They are supposed to be transient, and that is exactly the problem I can't save my script. eg. say I have a script that draws a rectangle and rotates it when the mouse is clicked. How do I save the rotation for the next time the script is opened?

Comment: What do you mean by *I can't save my script*? It is a `String` after all, and it is `Serializable`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Eg. var rotation = 0.0; if(Mouse.isClicked) rotation += 5.0;    How do I keep the rotation for the next time I start a script engine with the script?

Comment: It would be better if you provide the data that needs to be serialized/deserialized and a better explanation of your problem. Currently, we have no idea of your what you really need and how to achieve it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza edited the post show the script. What happens is every time the main application is closed and open I have to start a new script engine therefore losing things like the rotationAngle variable.

Comment: How about storing the rotation angle as well?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Storing? How?

Comment: Refer here: [using JavaScript variable in Java](http://kamleshkumar.com/tag/using-javascript-variable-in-java/) to see how to retrieve the value of a JavaScript variable to Java.